# Rails multiple controller has same action, Can we write single line route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have many controllers which has an action download_excel. Action generates xls file defined using axlsx gem.

Problem is many controllers have same action. Is there anyway to write a single line route in routes.rb file?

I tried.

```
match ':controller(/:download_excel)', :via => [:get]
```

and

```
resource "#{:controller}" do
  get download_excel, on: :collection
end
```

and

```
[:countries, :pricetypes].each do |file|
    resources "#{file}" do
      collection do
        get "#{file}"+'/excel' => "#{file}"+'#excel'
      end
    end
  end
```

etc. Nothing worked.
How can I write dynamic routes. Want to DRY code in routes as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

I use it as a catch all route, but if you want to your app to be restfull you should use the resources routes

Comment: I tried,
Actually its a collection method, and helps to generate xlsx file on whole collection.
If I try this It redirects to show action and takes action name as id.
I am new to rails.